# Unity Build Exception: Failed running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I build the project in unity i get this exception error

Exception: Failed running D:\2021.1.22f1\Editor\Data\Tools/InternalCallRegistrationWriter/InternalCallRegistrationWriter.exe -output="C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\UnityICallRegistration.cpp" -summary="C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\ICallSummary.txt" -assembly="C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.AndroidJNIModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.AnimationModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.AudioModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.CoreModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.GridModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.ImageConversionModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.IMGUIModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.InputLegacyModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.JSONSerializeModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.ParticleSystemModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.Physics2DModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.PhysicsModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.SharedInternalsModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.SpriteShapeModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.TextRenderingModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.TilemapModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.UIElementsModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.UIElementsNativeModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.UIModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.UnityAnalyticsModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.UnityConnectModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.UnityWebRequestModule.dll;C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip\UnityEngine.dll"

stdout:
stderr:

Exception non g�r�e�: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: L'acc�s au chemin d'acc�s 'C:\Users\PCI\Desktop\Codes To Reskin\Mr.Bullet_said gley\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\ICallSummary.txt' est refus�.
� System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
� System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
� System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
� System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
� System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
� System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
� Unity.InternalCallRegistrationWriter.Runner.DefaultRunner.Run(InternalCallOptions options)
� Unity.InternalCallRegistrationWriter.Runner.DefaultRunner.ParseOptionsAndRun(String[] args)
� Unity.InternalCallRegistrationWriter.Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0) UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.GenerateInternalCallSummaryFile (System.String icallSummaryPath, System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, System.String strippedDLLPath) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyStripper (UnityEditorInternal.UnityLinkerRunInformation runInformation) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssemblies (System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, UnityEditorInternal.BaseUnityLinkerPlatformProvider unityLinkerPlatformProvider, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider il2cppPlatformProvider, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry rcr, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at :0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Comment: move your project from Desktop to some folder that is not on the root of the drive and not in user folder like `c:\repos\Codes To Reskin`

Comment: It just looks like you have a Windows folder access issue.